# Gantt Chart Using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gantt-chart

I have three time series that are discontinuous. For example:

Task 1 starts at t1 and ends at t2 but, starts again at t3 and ends at t4 and so forth it. I did it in Plotly, but this platform has some restrictions for my purposes.

```
In            end   
01/01/1954  31/12/1956
01/01/1958  31/12/1959
01/01/1963  31/12/1966
01/01/1977  31/12/1983
01/01/1986  31/12/2000
20/06/2012  30/06/2012
01/07/2012  30/09/2012
01/10/2012  31/12/2012
01/01/2013  31/03/2013
01/04/2013  30/06/2013
```

That's it: This time serie ranges 01/01/1954 - 31/12/1956, then 01/01/1958 -  31/12/1959 and so on. I have 2 more stations. Dataset organization is flexible.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Dates inserted above are a slice of NM - UBA's time serie.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Use Matplotlib to plot this data as a Gantt Chart. Someone edited my post, so I lost the figure that I used as example.